# Error in Angular Material Tree when displaying big Data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I constructed an angular material Tree data that contains children depth > 6 and important length like :

```
const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussel sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
....
];
```

when trying to display the tree :

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      {{node.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

I get an error of Maximum call stack size exceeded :
[image]

i couldn't fix this bug, if any one can help ?

Comment: It means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth until you hit the call stack limit. OR `You can sometimes get this if you accidentally import/embed the same JavaScript file twice, worth checking in your resources tab of the inspector.`

Comment: Please provide a demo where I/we can reproduce an issue!

Comment: When using a nested tree and  the data of the tree is so  large,it throws RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error and some nodes are rendered with no content, So the solution i found to overcome this is to use a flat tree. it appears that the Tree with flat nodes can handle large data.

Comment: @a.oubela can you create a stackblitz demo to reproduce the issue ?